# Making Github GraphQL requests via curl

Tags: post, github, graphql, github-graphql

The following GraphQL query [runs perfectly fine in Github GraphQL Explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?variables=%7B%7D&query=query%20%7B%0A%20%20__schema%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20types%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20kind%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20description%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fields%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D):

```
$ cat GraphQL_query.graphql
query {
  __schema {
    types {
      name
      kind
      description
      fields {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

however, when I send it via `curl`:

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer token" -X POST -d "`cat GraphQL_query.graphql`" https://api.github.com/graphql
```

I'll get:

```
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v4"
}
```

What's wrong? How can I make it works? Thx.

Comment: This Q/A helped me find a [better Github search approach](https://medium.com/@suntong001/query-github-graphql-9a4547d33bad), FYI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `curl` syntax would look like this for that query:

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $GITHUB_PRODUCTION_TOKEN" https://api.github.com/graphql -X POST -d '{"query":"query { __schema { types { name kind description fields { name } } } }","variables":"{}"}'
```